# How to exclude values from a polynomial fit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, polynomials

I fit a polynomial to my data, as shown in the figure: [image]

Using the script:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.stats
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp

xdata = xvalues
ydata = yvalues

fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xdata, ydata + .00001005 , 3)
modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xdata) 

axes.plot(xdata, ydata,  '-')
xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata))
yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

axes.plot(xModel, yModel)
```

I want to exclude the region from 3.4 to 3.55 um. How can I do that in my script? Also I have NaNs that I am trying to get rid of in the original .fits file. Help would be valued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mask the values within your exclustion region and apply this mask to your fit function later

```
# Using random data here, since you haven't provided sample data
xdata = numpy.arange(3,4,0.01)
ydata = 2* numpy.random.rand(len(xdata)) + xdata

# Create mask (boolean array) of values outside of your exclusion region
mask = (xdata < 3.4) | (xdata > 3.55)

# Do the fit on all data (for comparison)
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xdata, ydata + .00001005 , 3)
modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xdata) 
xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata))
yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

# Do the fit on the masked data (i.e. only that data, where mask == True)
fittedParameters1 = numpy.polyfit(xdata[mask], ydata[mask] + .00001005 , 3)
modelPredictions1 = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters1, xdata[mask]) 
xModel1 = numpy.linspace(min(xdata[mask]), max(xdata[mask]))
yModel1 = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters1, xModel1)

# Plot stuff
axes.plot(xdata, ydata,  '-')
axes.plot(xModel, yModel)        # orange
axes.plot(xModel1, yModel1)      # green
```

gives

[image]

The green curve is now the fit with `3.4 < xdata 3.55` excluded. The orange curve is the fitout without an exclusion (for comparison)

If you want to exclude also possible nans in your `xdata` you can enhance the `mask` by the `numpy.isnan()` function like

```
# Create mask (boolean array) of values outside of your exclusion AND which ar not nan
xdata < 3.4) | (xdata > 3.55) & ~numpy.isnan(xdata)
```

Comment: When I try to divide the original data (e.g., ydata) by the curve with the masked data (e.g., ymodel1), now the dimensions are different, and I cannot divide the two. How to go around this?